# remove with bash lots of files with spaces in their names

Tags: bash, parsing, filenames

Okey, my question seems to be related to this one:
[Trouble in script with spaces in filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57830/trouble-in-script-with-spaces-in-filename)
but the answer doesn't seem to tackle the problem when you have to deal with a bunch of those files.
Let us say that I get some filenames of files that I want to erase with `find`, and that I put them in a text file. Then I want to delete them, with `rm`, say. `rm` seems not to be able to interpret the spaces of the filenames, even after I put the names inside quotes manually! 
What would you suggests?

Comment: If you could post what errors and what solution did you tried to recreate them that would be useful, or It might just be you're not quoting the variables.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you're actually *processing* the file list (which you haven't yet shown). Assuming you have them one per line in the file:

```
:: cat list
thishasnospaces
but this does
```

then even something like this won't work if they have spaces:

```
:: for fspec in $(cat list) ; do echo "rm -f \"${fspec}\"" ; done
rm -rf "thishasnospaces"
rm -rf "but"
rm -rf "this"
rm -rf "does"
```

That's because this treats all white space as identical. However, you *can* do it with a `while` loop:

```
:: cat list | while read ; do echo "rm -f \"$REPLY\""; done
rm -f "thishasnospaces"
rm -f "but this does"
```

You'll see that preserves the one per line aspect. Just remove the echo when you're happy it will work.

```
:: cat list | while read ; do rm -f "$REPLY"; done
```

---

But just keep in mind this may all be unnecessary. The `find` command already *has* the capability to delete files that it finds, bu use of the `-delete` option. If you can use that, there'll be far less messing about with spaces in the filenames.

Comment: Perfect. Oh,  I didn't known that find can delete, but It would have been bad to do it, there were a couple of exceptions that I do not want to delete that I manually pick.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a text file?
Try something like:

```
touch "a b"
touch "c d"
find . -name "* *" -exec rm "{}" \;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Because I want to inspect them before deletion.

Comment: OK then:
find . -name "* *" -exec echo "{}" >> test \;